# Is this a typo in React docs or I am not able to understand it?

Tags: reactjs

I was going through [displaying data](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/displaying-data.html) React guide, I am shown the following piece of React.js code alongwith `hello-react.html` file:

```js
var HelloWorld = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    return (
      <p>
        Hello, <input type="text" placeholder="Your name here" />!
        It is {this.props.date.toTimeString()}
      </p>
    );
  }
});

setInterval(function() {
  ReactDOM.render(
    <HelloWorld date={new Date()} />,
    document.getElementById('example')
  );
}, 500);
```

After going through it when I reach under the header [Reactive Updates](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/displaying-data.html#reactive-updates), I encounter the following sentence:

> Open hello-react.html in a web browser and type your name into the text field. Notice that React is only changing the time string in the UI — any input you put in the text field remains, even though you haven't written any code to manage this behavior.

I am really confused by the part

> any input you put in the text field remains, even though you haven't written any code to manage this behavior.

How is this behavior any different, whatever you type in the input fields remains there whether you use react or not? Can you explain please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The point is that React only updates the part that has changed (i.e.) the time instead of re-rendering the entire `<p>` tag. Contrast this with the code below (see fiddle):

```
setInterval(function() {
    document.getElementById('example').innerHTML = 
    '<p>'
        + 'Hello, <input type="text" placeholder="Your name here" />!'
        + 'It is' + (new Date).getTime()
    + '</p>'
}, 500);
```

https://jsfiddle.net/L1koa5nn/

Comment: Hum, I thought it meant that even though you wrote no code to tell the diff engine to update itself when the user typed in the input (i.e. onchange), it was still smart enough to not overwrite it with the old state (which was blank). In other words, the virtual D.O.M. auto updated itself on user input.

Comment: @m-a-r-c-e-l-i-n-o I agree with the first part (smart enough to not overwrite ...) but I don't understand what you mean by "the virtual D.O.M. auto updated itself on user input"? ... there's nothing to update?

Comment: If I started typing "Marc" into the input, I was under the impression that aside from the algorithm being smart enough to not overwrite "Marc" with a blank state, it would also begin to track a new state in which "Marc" exists (in the input as a value in the virtual dom). You could imagine a scenario where I wanted to clone the entire virtual dom, and reconstruct a replica of it in another page. I would expect the input field in that replica to contain the word "Marc", as it does in the original copy. Does that make sense?

Comment: @m-a-r-c-e-l-i-n-o I think I see what you're saying but how is that any different from when you type in "Marc" into a text field on a regular dom and make a copy of that? Wouldn't the replica also contain the word "Marc" in that case?

Comment: It would, but that's the regular dom retaining the state, not much surprise there. My question is whether or not React's virtual dom is retaining that state also. In theory, it doesn't have to, it could just be ignoring these shallow input states until the app explicitly tells the virtual dom to update the real dom with some value.